# モデレーションの理論

Tags: サポート, モデレーション, stackoverflow.blog

> これは [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.blog/authors/jeffatwood/) 氏によるブログ記事 [A Theory of Moderation](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) の翻訳です

---

スタック・オーバーフローにはコミュニティモデレーションが必要だと強く思います。ですので、ベータ版ではまずコミュニティからモデレーターを選び、ベータ版卒業後に選挙でモデレーターを選出することとしています。さて、モデレーターは具体的には何をするのでしょうか？その答えは**出来る限りの最小限です！**

2008年の初代スタック・オーバーフローFAQを書き起こした時から今に至るまで、私たちはコミュニティが力を発揮できるようにすることを目標としてきました：

> スタック・オーバーフローはユーザーによるユーザーのためのQ&Aコミュニティです！このサイトの運営の手助けをするには、まず信用度を集めないといけません。信用度の基本目的はコミュニティからの（かなり）おおよその信用度を示すことです。信用度は自然にもらうものではなく、他のユーザーに納得してもらった上で得られるものです。

当ネットワークはユーザーが管理できるように設計されています。モデレーションの負担は複数の小さなタスクで分担され、そのタスクは通常ユーザーでもこなせるものです。例えば、信用度による権限で：

- 15で通報ができる
- 500で新しいユーザーの投稿をレビューできる
- 2000でなんでも質問・回答を編集できる
- 3000で質問をクローズ出来る
- 10000で削除・復活投票が出来る、モデレーションダッシュボードが見える
- 15000で質問を保護できる

コミュニティの自己管理があっても、たまにモデレーターが必要になります。モデレーターは人間例外処理機です。通常のプロセスで管理できないケースがあった場合、人間がそれを管理しないとコミュニティが停止する危険性があります。

モデレーターの最も基本的なタスクは通報の管理です。信用度15以上のユーザーには各投稿に「通報」ボタンがついています。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

投稿は「スパム、失礼又は暴言、又はモデレーターによる対応が必要」として通報ができます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

その後、モデレーターのヘッダーに通報の数が記載されます。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

サイト上で、何かの悪用、奇妙な、或いは何か対応が必要である投稿を見かけたら、すぐに通報してください！モデレーターの基本的な仕事は各通報をレビューして、必要に応じて対応することです。

極めてまれな状況にも対応できるために、モデレーターには特別な権限が付与されています。

- モデレーターの投票には拘束力があります。投票が出来る箇所（クローズ投票、削除投票等）ではモデレーターが投票する時点でそのアクションが確定されます。
- モデレーターは投稿のロックができます。ロックされた質問はいじれません。
- モデレーターは質問を保護することができます。保護すると信用度10以上のユーザーしか投稿・編集等ができません。
- モデレーターはアカウントを停止することができます。必要に応じてユーザーの削除も行います。
- モデレーターは質問やタグのマージ、タグシノニムの設定等もデータベースを大幅に変えるアクションを取ることができます。

スタック・オーバーフローのコミュニティモデレーターには、以下が期待されます：

1. モデレーターとしてのアクションがコミュニティ全体に影響を与えるため、より高度な行動意識が必要とされます。その信用度の高さから、当サイトの開発者やコミュニティ管理者と同様の権限が与えられます。
2. モデレーターとしての目的は**適切なアプローチでコミュニティをリードする**です。コミュニティメンバーを尊敬しながらフェアな対応を取らないといけません。
3. 出来る限り、自分のアクション（実行した/しようとしている）の投稿にコメントを残してその考え方を共有します。そのコメントを通じてコミュニティ全体に当サイトのルールやスタンダードを広げることができます。
4. サイトの質を守るため、質問のクローズや削除を行います。
5. 通報を定期的にレビューして、対応します。
6. 口論が発生した場合、直接ユーザーとのプライベートなやり取りでその口論を介在します。

モデレーターは100％ボランティアであり、辞退することも可能ですが、モデレーターとして2つの義務があります：

1. [Moderator Agreement](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement)に30日以内に合意して、サイトをアクテイブに利用し続けること。
2. 他のモデレーターと協力して、モデレーター間で合意を取ること。もし協力ができないなら、モデレーターを辞退させるプロセスもあります。

モデレーターのタスクは基本的に平凡です。スパムを削除したり、関係のない質問をクローズしたり、ワーストな投稿を削除したりします。

モデレーターがコミュニティにとって最大限の効力を持つアクションをできるだけ最小限に取る、というのが理想です。モデレーター権限の使い方や使うタイミングを賢明に選びコミュニティをリードするのが良いモデレーターの特徴です。