# 暫定モデレーターを追加募集します

Tags: 討議, モデレーション

**募集は終了しました**。[新モデレーターYuki Inoueさん、おめでとうございます！](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2533)

---

Stack Exchange では、コミュニティが充分成長してモデレーターの公開選挙ができるようになるまでは、Stack Exchange 側から暫定モデレーターを 3 名任命する運用としています。

今回、[tomute](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/33/tomute) さんがモデレーター役を退任され、暫定モデレーター枠に 1 名の空きができましたので、追加募集して 3 名体制を整えたいと考えています。そして、選定にあたってはできるだけボトムアップなプロセスを踏みたいと思っています：この人にモデレーターになってほしい、というユーザーがいらっしゃいましたら、是非推薦をお願いします。

#### 推薦プロセス

- この質問に回答を投稿することで推薦となります。候補者一人につき回答も一つでお願いします。
- 自薦は大歓迎です。自薦は単に「興味あります、これまでの活動履歴で判断してもらえれば」という意思表示にすぎません。選考において他薦との違いは特にないと考えていただいて大丈夫です。
- 候補者について教えてください。Stack Exchange 上、それに限らず他のサイトでの活動など私たちが判断する上で参考になる情報を加えていただけると助かります。
- 推薦されたら！：回答を編集して、末尾に推薦を受けるかどうかをご記入ください。また、連絡が確実に取れるよう、登録メールアドレスが正しいかどうかをご確認ください。推薦をお受けいただける場合、任意の自己紹介を回答に加えていただいてかまいません。参考にさせていただきます。なお、モデレーターはボランティアとしての活動なので、推薦されたからといって受けなければというプレッシャーを感じる必要は一切ありません。

  > 推薦を受けさせていただきます / 辞退させていただきます。
  >
  > ..です。..に住んでいます。..したことがあります。…が好きです。(全て任意)
  >   ..時から..時の間アクティブなことが多いです。その他補足事項。

#### 私たちが求めるモデレーター像

コミュニティの成長と運営に深く関わっているユーザーを理想としています。

- サイトに数週間以上継続的に参加
- メタでの議論に参加する意欲をみせている
- サイトの使い方・方針を見本をもって示し、常に忍耐強く、丁寧に相手に接している
- [A Theory of Moderation](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2517/%e3%83%a2%e3%83%87%e3%83%ac%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%81%ae%e7%90%86%e8%ab%96)で取り上げられている、言葉で表しにくい諸々の特徴をもちあわせている

#### 推薦用テンプレート

よろしければお使い下さい。

```
<a href="https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/UserID">
<img src="https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/UserID.png"></a>
<a href="https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/UserID">
<img src="https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/UserID.png"></a>

* 推薦理由その1
* 推薦理由その2
* ..
```

<sub>`UserID` は、候補者のプロフィールページのURLから取得できます。`https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/10/jmac`であれば 10 です。</sub>

Comment: 推薦の締め切り日時のようなものはありますか？

Comment: @Yosh 来週火曜日（１週間後）です。

Comment: 推薦文の、「(下記)フォーマット」は、何かあるのでしょうか。。？ フリースタイルで記述してしまいましたが、問題があればご指摘お願いいたします。

Comment: @YukiInoue フリースタイルです。ブロックに例がありますが、別に自分の好きなように答えたらいいです。

Comment: 推薦文のフォーマットの例が抜けてたので追加しました

Answer (score 9):

せっかくなので、自己推薦します。

[image]


[image]

### 経歴

- [「研究熱心」のバッジ](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/89/socratic) を持っています。このサイトにおいて、どのように質問を行っていったらいいのかについて、いろいろ考えてきましたし、それを実践してきた、つもりです。
- メタもそこそこ参加してきました。

### 推薦理由、もあれなんで、意気込みをば。

スタックオーバーフローには、ほぼほぼパブリックベータのスタートした直後ぐらいから参加していました。はじめは、たまに質問する質問者として。次第にいろいろ他にもやるようになりました。

今現在の私は、 スタックオーバーフローは、以下の行為からなる、「プログラミングに関する技術的なQ&Aの収集・蓄積のためのコミュニティ」であると理解しています。

1. 質問行為
2. 回答行為
3. モデレーション行為（諸々の投票、編集、メタ、etc）

これらの行為全てに対して実際にやってみて、どうやったら上記のコミュニティにとっての目的を果たせるか、どういう仕組みでスタックオーバーフローが動作しているのか、わりと分かってきたと思います。それを踏まえた上で、今自分がコミュニティ対して貢献できることを、日々地道に行っている、というのが今の私のスタックオーバーフローへの参加の仕方です。

Moderator になるということは、上記のモデレーション行為として行えることが、さらに追加されることなのだと理解しています。（そして、それを行うことが期待されるのだと。）なったことがないのでわからないですが、一応次のようなことを行うことになるのではないか、と想像しています。

1. フラグ(通報)処理
2. コミュニティメンバ間でのトラブル対応
3. コミュニティの総意を決定する必要がある場合に、これを行う。しかしこれを行う際には、コミュニティに対して説明可能であり、かつ、その決定内容自体はコミュニティから提出されなければならない。
4. Be Nice

仮に上記であったとして、 2. 以外はおそらく問題なくできるのではないか、と思っています。 2. についての懸念点は、正直に言うとそういったことをまだここでやったことがないので、実際にやってみて、なるべくうまくモデーレションしてみます、としか言えないと思っています。

ただ、何が原則として従うべきか、というのは理解していると思っています。 Be Nice です。これに基づいて、対応するのならば、そんなにひどい Moderator になってしまうことは、基本的にないだろうとは考えています。

Comment: 応援します。メタ的な活動を活発にするユーザーの投稿は回答中心である傾向が強くありますが、質問も多くなさって来た Yuki Inoue さんがモデレーターとして参加なされば、視点のバランスが取れてとても良いと思います。

Answer (score 6):

[mjy](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/3054/mjy)さんを推薦します。

- 継続的に、当サイトにて活動をしています。
- meta にも積極的に参加しています。

  - 特に、何が SO においてふさわしい、ふさわしくないか（オントピックか、オフトピックか)系の質問に対しては、明確で一貫した回答をしています。
  - 当サイトで発生した、明文化されていなかったり、不明瞭であったりする議題に対して、問題提起的なメタ質問を、積極的に投稿しています。
- meta での投稿などから、「私たちが求めるモデレーター像」に合致していると考え、推薦しました。

---

mjy です。過分な評価をいただき恐縮です。
ご推薦いただき光栄ではありますが、今回は辞退させていただくことにしました。
理由は以下です。

- 私のレスポンスタイムが長いため、特にスパムに対する対応などのモデーレーターの責を果せそうにない事
- モデレーターの役割として示されている「プライベートなやり取りでその口論を介在」といった行為はやるべきでないと考えており、私自身やりたくない事
- 一般的な投票ができなくなってしまうのが残念に感じる事

最後の理由は、活発に活動されている方をモデレーターに推薦しづらいと感じている理由でもあります。

モデレーターをこなされている方には頭が下がる思いです。
今後も一般ユーザーとして参加し、協力していければと思っています。
tomute さんお疲れさまでした。

Comment: もちろん辞退してもかまいませんが、念のため説明させていただきます：　①　レスポンスタイムについてですが、スパム等の緊急なことは少ないし、一般ユーザーが通報することでも対応できます。②　モデレーターメッセージとは呼びますが、正直には当サイトで１回しか使っていないし、その時弊職が送りました。③　一般投票はまだできますが、クローズ・削除のみが特別になります。