# 新モデレーターYuki Inoueさん、おめでとうございます！

Tags: 討議, モデレーション

今日から[Yuki Inoue](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/754/yuki-inoue)さんがモデレーターになりました。おめでとうございます！

[image: Yuki Inoueのプロフィール]

[ento](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento)さんと[unarist](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/8000/unarist)さんと一緒にこのコミュニティを成長しながら管理します。宜しくお願いします！