# 「モデレーションの理論 」へのリンク先変更

Tags: 機能の要求, 完了, 翻訳

ブログ記事 ["A Theory of Moderation"](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/) へのリンクを、その翻訳である投稿[「モデレーションの理論」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/3054)へ変更することを提案します。
ざっと見たところ、以下3ページにリンクがあります。

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators
- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators
- https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators

Comment: よく見つかりました。翻訳済みでしたか・・・時間を無駄にしてしまいました。ありがとうございます！更新させていただきます。

Comment: @jmac ？ 誤解があるかも知れませんね。翻訳として示した投稿は jmac さんのものです。翻訳ありがとうございます。

Comment: ヘルプの方は完了していますが、ストリングの方（ユーザーページ）はコード内に入っているため、簡単には変更ができません（もしするのであれば、このケースだけではなく、将来に同じ問題があれば簡単に訂正出来るようなシステムとかを開発したほうが効率的だと思います）