# 行動規範に沿っているか否か最終的に判断するのは誰ですか？

Tags: 討議, 行動規範

当サイト内での行いが[行動規範](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct)に沿っているか否か最終的に判断するは誰ですか？
コミュニティーでしょうか？ モデレーターやStack Exchange社でしょうか？

（モデレーターもコミュニティーの一員であり、一般のユーザーと同じくコミュニティーの判断に関わりますが、それはそれとして、ここでは区別しました）

Comment: 本来これは運営者の意思の問題であり、運営者が明確に回答できることですが、おそらくStack Exchange社から回答は得られないと思いますので、「サポート」タグではなく「討議」タグで質問いたしました。

Comment: 多言語版サイト全体を担当なさっている Nicolas さんと相談し、この投稿を元にした投稿を Meta Stack Exchange へ英語で投稿してみました (aki さんが仲介してくださいました。ありがとうございます :)。 → [Who is the most responsible for the new Code of Conduct?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316301/341401)

Answer (score 5):

究極的には、運営側の Stack Exchange チームです。

より適切には、ここには「権限の連鎖」があると言うべきです。決定権には 3 つのレイヤーがあります。

1 つ目のレイヤーは通常のユーザーです。ユーザーは行動規範に違反していると思われる投稿を通報したり、それに対してコメントしたりします。

2 つ目のレイヤーはモデレーターです。通報を見て行動を決めます。つまり、行動規範に違反していることに同意するなら削除などの対応をし、そうでないならそのままにします。

多くの場合、連鎖はここで止まります。ただし、行動規範を理由に削除されたことに投稿者が気づいた場合、ヘルプページの[問い合わせフォーム](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/contact)から Stack Exchange チームに問い合わせることができます。

3 つ目、そして最後のレイヤーは Stack Exchange チームです（[コミュニティー・チーム](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99338/341401)と呼ばれています）。このチームが送られてきた問い合わせを処理します。そしてこれが最終決定です。ただしもし問題となる箇所が日本語独特の表現になっていて英語で説明しにくい場合、日本語を喋れるコミュニティ・マネージャーも対応することになるでしょう。

この説明が分かりにくければ、まず[「モデレーションの理論」](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/19110)をご覧ください。モデレーターがどういう役割を担っているのかが具体的に説明されています。

---

補足：この投稿は、Meta Stack Exchange に投稿された質問 ["Who is the most responsible for the new Code of Conduct?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316301/341401) および ["Set a benchmark on acceptable behaviour"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/284569/341401) への回答たちを参考にして書きました。特に、以下の回答を参考にしています。

- [Shadow Wizard さん](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/152859/shadow-wizard)の[回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316303/341401) (大筋はこの回答を和訳しています)
- [Glorfindel さん](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/295232/glorfindel)の[回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316302/341401) (英語以外の言語に特化した部分の回答があります)
- [ArtOfCode さん](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/262823/artofcode)の[回答](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/284571/341401) ("Be Nice" ポリシー時代の類似回答です)

Comment: "Be Nice"はあくまで"Code of Conduct"に内包されるものだと思っていましたが、ポリシーの置き換えだったのですね。

Comment: @cubick さん、ある意味では内包されているのかもしれませんが、行動規範はヘルプページの be-nice と behavior を置き換えるものだと聞いています。現在 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice の方は https://ja.stackoverflow.com/conduct にリダイレクトするようになっていますね。

Answer (score 1):

投稿してこられたユーザーの方達が新行動規範の中で動く意思を持っていることを前提として回答します。少し冗長かもしれませんがお許しください。

しばしばスタックオーバーフローでは、コミュニティのメンバーが決める事だという表現が見られます。

しかし、私たちは、現実的には、こうして投稿してきた人たちの中でしか判断することはできません。

誰でも投稿することは出来る。しかし、その投稿してきた人たちの中で、投稿していない全ユーザーの事を考慮しながら決める。現実的にはそうせざるを得ません。全ユーザーが決めていく、というのは、誰でも意見を述べてもいいということであり、投稿する自由もしない自由も認められているということだと解釈しています。

そしてその投稿してきた人たちの中で、**最も説得力のあるものを選ぶ**ことです。もしくは意見を集約してハイブリッドな形にまとめることでしょうか。そこが、自治社会の力の発揮地点だと思いますし、そうしたものを選ぶ目を持てるかどうかで、質が決まって来るのではないでしょうか。

しかし、そうした説得力のあるものを言う人が注目を浴び、その人に周りの目が移ることは実は問題です。自分たち自身で自治社会であることを放棄したようなものです。議論にならなくなります。その人はその時限りの意見で説得力があった。それにとどまると考えるべきです

何度かいい投稿を出していても、次は少し外れてしまう事を言ってしまうというのは、誰にでもよくあることだし、それは最初の一投稿目かもしれません。私たち自身変数だし、議題もまた変数です。かけ合わせれば値が違うのも当然です。いつでもどんな時でも古い投稿でも構わないので、広く受け入れるべきでしょう。

自治社会の人たちは様々な意見や思いを持っている事が多くても、もしかしたらその意見は、投稿されないまま終わってしまうかもしれません。

私たちも自治社会であると銘打つなら、規約から逸脱したものでない限り、広く意見を受け入れる姿勢を持つことだろうと思います。このこと自体が、新行動規範に沿うものであると思っています。

スタックオーバーフローのコミュニティからはやや外れた考えで、一般的なものなのですが、意見を出すことに躊躇する人や結局説得力があるとみなされなかった方達の意見の方が多くあると思います。しかし、私の経験上、そういうことを考えることと、頭を働かせたこと自体が重要であると確信しています。

我々は出て来た投稿だけで判断するしか現実的にはできません。本当はうまく表現が出来なかっただけかもしれません。しかし、その人がそれだけ考えて来てくれたこと、投稿したことに敬意を表することです。マイナスがつくことはあります。ここを展開すると話が膨らみますが、それは参考数字みたいなものかなと。前にも述べたように、どのような思いでそれだけの票が入っているのかを示すものではなく、あくまでも結果だと思います。

様々な人がいるとおもいます。プログラミングに極めて先鋭されている人でも、こうした議論は苦手だという方は、割と多いのではないかと思います。

**結論：新行動規範に従う意思を持つことを前提としたうえで**
コミュニティのメンバー全体で決めるという事は、現実的には、広く意見を受け入れるという姿勢を私たちが持ったうえで、投稿されて来た内容の中から、全ユーザーの事を考えて、説得力のあるものを選ぶ行為。推敲して、投稿をして、意見を出すという事。投稿する自由もしない自由も含まれるもの。程度の差こそあれ、その人がそれだけ考えてきたこと、頭を働かせたこと自体が、貴重であることは忘れない方がよい。
一応、私の考えの推移としては、以上です。

私のような新参者が意見を言う事自体も、一つのいい事じゃないかなと思ってます。割と早い時期からMETAにも参加しています。

最終的に決めるのはコミュニティだと思いますが、その中のどういうものを決めるのかということについては、上で私の意見を述べました。

> モデレーターもコミュニティーの一員であり、一般のユーザーと同じくコミュニティーの判断に関わりますが、それはそれとして、ここでは区別しました

これはそのままで、モデレーターはコミュニティーの一員で、一般のユーザーと同じであるというのは、私の考えと同一です。

Stack Exchange社ではないと思います。私はそのあたりには特に詳しくありませんが、Stack Exchange社だと、逆に我々の考える余地なく一義的に決めてもらわねば私たちも混乱してしまいます。それとも、私たちが最終的にまとめ上げた意見に、Stack Exchange社が裁可を行うということでしょうか。Stack Exchange社であるという事になると、また変わってきますが、私はユーザー全体側から考え始めたので、そこはわかりません。Stack Exchange社について詳しい方が、その方向性から回答を書いていただくのがいいとも思いますが、Stack Exchange社自体が、全ユーザーの自治社会だと銘打っている以上、我々に任せて居るということになり、そこにStack Exchange社が介入されるということは、自治社会ではないのではないか。という事になります。（それとも自治社会という言葉にこだわりすぎでしょうか。）ちなみに通報等、様々な異常事態は、最終的にStack Exchange社へ行くというような事は何となくわかりますが、きわめて例外的な場合ではないでしょうか。

**nekketsuuuさんの回答を読んだ後で。これは質問ではありません。**

StackExchange社が最終的に判断を行うというのはわかりました。しかし私だけでしょうか。その回答だと、結局何も言っていないような気がするのです。社会構造上、スタックオーバーフローが生き物のように独立しているわけではないこと、背後に会社があるからこそ動いており、最終的にはいろいろな案件がそこで処理されるだろうという事はわかります。それがmjyさんが求めておられる回答ならば文句はありませんが、自分は違う回答を書きましたが、変な話、どこか、それはそうだろうと思ってしまいました。Stack Exchange社が最終的に決めるなら、具体的な事案が生じれば、我々が話すのではなくて、Stack Exchange社に最初から決めてもらった方が、内部のいざこざもなく、よっぽどスッキリするような気がするのです。ひょっとしてこれは建前で、実際のところは全てモデレーターを通じた話だと思うようになりました。
そして、じゃあ、ユーザー達の中で話し合った時に、モデレーターに到達するかしないかのうちに、（ユーザーの中で論じられれば、モデレーターもそこにいるのが普通だと思うのですが、）その時に判断するのは、誰なのでしょうか？mjyさんの質問を勝手に変えるような事をいいますが、私はその方が大事だと思いました。その時モデレーターだという事であれば、なぜモデレーターになるのでしょうか？結局ユーザーの中にとどまらないよというのであれば、じゃあ最初からStack Exchange社に裁可を仰げばどうでしょうか。

確かに質問を素直に読めば、どんな時でも**最終的には**Stack Exchange社なんだろうと思うんです。でも、それって、結局は何でもそうじゃないですか？

ユーザーの中で話が止まったら、Stack Exchange社のところにはいかないと思います。
ユーザーの中で話が止まるとき、じゃあ誰が最終的にコードオブコンダクトに違反しているかどうかを決めるのですか？
それがまとまらないのならモデレーターやStack Exchange社にいくのはわかります。で、まとまった時というのは誰が決めているんですか？そういう事が一切ないというのであれば、最初からモデレーターを通じたStack Exchange社でいいんじゃないですか？

そのため、私はモデレーターをも一ユーザーであるとみなしたうえで、ユーザーの中で話し合うように論理を展開したつもりです。（そういう時はきっとMETA話になりそうだからです。）最後にStack Exchange社にいくのは極めて例外的な場合と書きました。

じゃあ、ユーザー内に留まるときってどういうときなんでしょうか？その時の姿勢こそがコードオブコンダクトとみんなで向き合う時点だと思ったのです。冒頭にも書きましたが、これは質問ではないので、お答えしていただかなくてもいいです。すでにこの質問に対する答えは、Stack　Exchange社であるという明確な解答が得られています。しかし私は、本当に正常な判断をできるかどうかわからないようなユーザーの誰かに任せるよりは、もうStack Exchange社に直接任せた方が、問題を起こした方も権威的に納得がいき、また、ここにいる他ユーザーとの関係も悪化することは少ないと思います。そのため、私たちがコードオブコンダクトに即しているかを私たちが判断するのではなくて、私たちはそれに違反しないようにだけ気を付けていればいいのだなと得心しました。私はそういうのを見れば、モデレーターに通報しようと思います。（ただ、コードオブコンダクトに沿っているかどうかを一ユーザーがわからないのに、通報するとどうして判断できるんでしょう。私には少し謎が多いです。）しかし、なんとなく怪しいことはわかるでしょうから、そういう時は通報をする。その方が迷いが無くていいと判断します。きっと、コードオブコンダクトに沿わないような事件はかなりはっきりとわかるような事案なのではないかと推察します。もう少し具体的な事件が起きてからまた考えようと思います。
毎度長文失礼しました。