# モデレーションレポート (2018年)

Tags: 討議

I would appreciate a translation of this question.

---

スタック・オーバーフロー日本語版における、モデレーションレポートを共有したいと思います。

Stack Exchangeサイトの特徴として、それらがどのようにしてモデレートされているかです。

> 当ネットワークはユーザーが管理できるように設計されています。モデレーションの負担は複数の小さなタスクで分担され、そのタスクは通常ユーザーでもこなせるものです。
>   -- [モデレーションの理論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/3060) / [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

確かに[モデレーター](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/)と呼ばれるユーザーもいますが、かなりの部分のモデレーションは、サイトへの貢献によって得られた権限を使用して、多くの一般ユーザーの協力によって行われています。
１人ひとりが少しの時間と労力を費やし、参加するみんなで多くの事を成し遂げています。

私たちが新年を迎えるにあたり、ここで一緒に協力しあう仲間に感謝するために少しだけ時間をかけて振り返ってみましょう。 そのため、スタック・オーバーフローで行われたモデレートが過去12ヶ月間のアクティビティでどのように分類されるかを説明します。

```
Action                                  Moderators Community¹ 
--------------------------------------- ---------- --------- 
Users suspended²                               0          4  
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue         76        479  
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue             3        114  
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue      23        514  
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue            31        172  
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue            336       1899  
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue            13        921  
Tags merged                                    6          0  
Tag synonyms proposed                          7          0  
Tag synonyms created                           5          0  
Tag highlight language set                    11          0  
Revisions redacted                             1          0  
Questions reopened                            12         20  
Questions migrated                             2          0  
Questions flagged⁴                             7        149  
Questions closed                              56        194  
Question flags handled⁴                      111         45  
Posts undeleted                                3        108  
Posts locked                                   0          8  
Posts deleted⁵                                66       1767  
Posts bumped                                   0       1987  
Escalations to the CM team                     5          0  
Comments undeleted                             8          0  
Comments flagged                               0         52  
Comments deleted⁶                            322       1155  
Comment flags handled                         38         14  
Answers flagged                                5        371  
Answer flags handled                         207        169  
All comments on a post moved to chat           4          0
```

#### 脚注

¹ ここでの「コミュニティー」とは[スタック・オーバーフローのユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users)を指し、名前の横にダイヤモンドの付くユーザー(モデレーター)と自動処理を行う[Communityユーザー(ボット)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)は**除きます**。

² システムは次の3つの理由でユーザーを一時停止する場合があります： ユーザーが以前に一時停止を受けた後に再生成されたとき、スパムや悪用のために破棄された後に再生成されたとき、アカウントがネットーワーク全体で一時停止の措置を受けたとき。

³ 送信済みのレビューが全て含まれます（スキップされたものは除きます）。2つの編集の提案を承認するために必要なレビューは2とカウントされます。モデレーションのアクションの頻度を示すためで、通報などにも当てはまります。

⁴ クローズの通報は含まれます（クローズや再オープンの投票は*除きます*）。

⁵ その他のアクションによって引き起こされる多数の自動削除は含まれません。

⁶ 投稿者本人によって削除されたコメントも含まれます（いくつかの通報されたコメントです）。

(こちらは、[@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9)さんが作成したSQLクエリで、Meta Stack Exchange に@ Shog9によって[投稿](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/378415/564240)されたものです。Arigato Gozaimasu m_ _m。）

---

この投稿は[@Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/78/nicolas-chabanovsky)さんの投稿を元に翻訳を行いました。
(A lot of thanks to [@Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/78/nicolas-chabanovsky) !)

Answer (score 4):

英語版での投稿では過去の結果と比較して「モデレーターとコミュニティーユーザーとのモデレーション比率」みたいなものを見ているようなので、同じ視点で英語版との比較をしてみました。
(モデレーターによる対応が多いと感じたものについて、何か施策を行って改善したかを見ているようです)

ただしそもそもの(絶対的な)投稿数が違いますし、サイトごとでユーザーに解放された操作なども違っていると思うので、あくまでざっくりとした比較になります。

- 網掛け部分が「Moderators + Community = 合計」のうち、どれくらいCommunityがアクションを行っているかの割合(自治率とでも言いましょうか)
- 赤字にしたのが英語版と比較して日本語版での数値が低いもの
- 青字にしたのが英語版と比較して日本語版での数値が高いもの

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

何か気づきがあればコメントや別の回答で意見を頂ければと思います。