# モデレーションレポート (2019年)

Tags: 討議

翻訳をしてくれた[@aki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/14055/aki)に感謝します。

---

スタック・オーバーフローにおける、モデレーションレポートを共有したいと思います。

Stack Exchangeサイトの特徴として、それらがどのようにしてモデレートされているかです。

> 当ネットワークはユーザーが管理できるように設計されています。モデレーションの負担は複数の小さなタスクで分担され、そのタスクは通常ユーザーでもこなせるものです。
>   -- [モデレーションの理論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/3060) / [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

確かに[モデレーター](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/)と呼ばれるユーザーもいますが、かなりの部分の*モデレーション*は、サイトへの貢献によって得られた権限を使用して、多くの一般ユーザーの協力によって行われています。１人ひとりが少しの時間と労力を費やし、参加するみんなで多くの事を成し遂げています。

私たちが新年を迎えるにあたり、ここで一緒に協力しあう仲間に感謝するために少しだけ時間をかけて振り返ってみましょう。数字ほど新年をお祝いするにふさわしいものはありません。スタック・オーバーフローで行われたモデレーションが過去12ヶ月間のアクティビティでどのように分類されるかを説明します。

```
                  Action                  Moderators Community¹
----------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                          0           2
Users destroyed³                          0           0
Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue     109         501
Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue        14          21
Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue  6           175
Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue        37          131
Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue         151         1871
Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue        9           364
Tags merged                               6           0
Tag synonyms proposed                     5           1
Tag synonyms created                      5           0
Tag highlight language set                6           0
Revisions redacted                        3           0
Questions reopened                        17          0
Questions migrated                        1           0
Questions flagged⁵                        12          144
Questions closed                          103         66
Question flags handled⁵                   133         23
Posts undeleted                           1           70
Posts locked                              0           13
Posts deleted⁶                            120         1558
Posts bumped                              0           1911
Comments undeleted                        13          0
Comments flagged                          0           40
Comments deleted⁷                         415         993
Comment flags handled                     38          1
Answers flagged                           4           275
Answer flags handled                      238         41
All comments on a post moved to chat      2           0
```

#### 脚注

¹ ここでの「コミュニティー」とは[スタック・オーバーフローのユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users)を指し、名前の横にダイヤモンドの付くユーザー(モデレーター)と自動処理を行う[Communityユーザー(ボット)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)は**除きます**。

² システムは次の3つの理由でユーザーを一時停止する場合があります： ユーザーが以前に一時停止を受けた後に再生成されたとき、スパムや悪用のために破棄された後に再生成されたとき、アカウントがネットーワーク全体で一時停止の措置を受けたとき。

³ 「破棄された」ユーザーは、投稿したすべての質問(回答、コメント)とともに削除されます。[Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ 送信済みのレビューが全て含まれます(スキップされたものは除きます)。2つの編集の提案を承認するために必要なレビューは2とカウントされます。モデレーションのアクションの頻度を示すためで、通報などにも当てはまります。

⁵ クローズの通報は含まれます(クローズや再オープンの投票は*除き*ます)。

⁶ その他のアクションによって引き起こされる多数の自動削除は含まれません。

⁷ 投稿者本人によって削除されたコメントも含まれます(いくつかの通報されたコメントです)。

#### 参考文献

- 昨年からの数字の変化を知りたい方はこちら: [モデレーションレポート (2018年)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2912/78)...
- [このレポートは他のサイトでも確認](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222019%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)できます
- 或いは[全サイトでクローズ及び再オープンされた質問の数に関する詳細情報](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/341507/2019-a-year-in-closing)を熟読

みなさんにとって2020年が素晴らしい一年となりますように...

---

(SQLクエリを作成し、本家にて[最初の投稿](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392550/)を書いてくれた[@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9)に感謝します。)

Answer (score 6):

今回は [英語版でのやり取り](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392550) を参考に、[2018年のデータ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2912) と比較した増減率も出してみました。

網掛け部分は昨年も出した結果を踏まえて、どれくらいコミュニティがアクションを行っているか = "自治率" 的な割合です。

- 赤字は前年(2018)と比較して数値が低いもの
- 青字は前年(2018)と比較して数値が高いもの

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

(ユーザー、投稿ともに)絶対数が異なるので単純比較はできませんが、あくまでご参考に英語版との比較も置いておきます。

- 赤字は英語版と比較して日本語版での数値が低いもの
- 青字は英語版と比較して日本語版での数値が高いもの

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

---

(追記)

[クローズ理由の内訳](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341507) からSOjaの部分を抜き出してみました。

- それぞれより細かい選択肢があったりしますが、一番多い「オフトピック」は「英語質問」なのかなと思います。
- 二番目に多い「詳細な情報が必要」は肝心のソースコードやエラーメッセージが無かったりなどでしょうか。体感的にもこちらに該当する質問が多い気がします。
  なお、MSE各サイトでもこちらの理由によるクローズ率を出してみると、全体平均では17%でした。多いサイトでは50%を超える(!)のでピンキリですが、平均より少しだけ割合が高いSOjaではこの部分に対しての取り組みが必要？

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]