# モデレーションレポート (2020年)

Tags: 討議

スタック・オーバーフローにおける、モデレーションレポートを共有したいと思います。

Stack Exchangeサイトの特徴として、それらがどのようにしてモデレートされているかです。

> 当ネットワークはユーザーが管理できるように設計されています。モデレーションの負担は複数の小さなタスクで分担され、そのタスクは通常ユーザーでもこなせるものです。
> -- [モデレーションの理論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/3060) / [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

確かに[モデレーター](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/)と呼ばれるユーザーもいますが、かなりの部分の*モデレーション*は、サイトへの貢献によって得られた権限を使用して、多くの一般ユーザーの協力によって行われています。１人ひとりが少しの時間と労力を費やし、参加するみんなで多くの事を成し遂げています。

私たちが新年を迎えるにあたり、ここで一緒に協力しあう仲間に感謝するために少しだけ時間をかけて振り返ってみましょう。数字ほど新年をお祝いするにふさわしいものはありません。スタック・オーバーフローで行われたモデレーションが過去12ヶ月間のアクティビティでどのように分類されるかを説明します。

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 2 | 3 |
| Users destroyed³ | 8 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 3 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 82 | 220 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 7 | 31 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 15 | 80 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 35 | 131 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 194 | 1882 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 25 | 386 |
| Tags merged | 4 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 4 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 7 | 0 |
| Tag highlight language set | 2 | 0 |
| Questions reopened | 10 | 0 |
| Questions migrated | 2 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 11 | 229 |
| Questions closed | 188 | 58 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 206 | 34 |
| Posts unlocked | 1 | 0 |
| Posts undeleted | 5 | 87 |
| Posts locked | 0 | 25 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 110 | 1814 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 2148 |
| Comments undeleted | 6 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 0 | 184 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 600 | 1210 |
| Comment flags handled | 177 | 8 |
| Answers flagged | 6 | 237 |
| Answer flags handled | 216 | 27 |

#### 脚注

¹ ここでの「コミュニティー」とは[スタック・オーバーフローのユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users)を指し、名前の横にダイヤモンドの付くユーザー(モデレーター)と自動処理を行う[Communityユーザー(ボット)](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)は**除きます**。

² システムは次の3つの理由でユーザーを一時停止する場合があります： ユーザーが以前に一時停止を受けた後に再生成されたとき、スパムや悪用のために破棄された後に再生成されたとき、アカウントがネットーワーク全体で一時停止の措置を受けたとき。

³ 「破棄された」ユーザーは、投稿したすべての質問(回答、コメント)とともに削除されます。[Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ 送信済みのレビューが全て含まれます(スキップされたものは除きます)。2つの編集の提案を承認するために必要なレビューは2とカウントされます。モデレーションのアクションの頻度を示すためで、通報などにも当てはまります。

⁵ クローズの通報は含まれます(クローズや再オープンの投票は*除き*ます)。

⁶ その他のアクションによって引き起こされる多数の自動削除は含まれません。

⁷ 投稿者本人によって削除されたコメントも含まれます(いくつかの通報されたコメントです)。

#### 参考文献

- 昨年からの数字の変化を知りたい方はこちら: [モデレーションレポート (2019年)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3182/)...
- このレポートは他のサイトでも確認できます。([2020年分](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222020%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22))

---

(SQLクエリを作成してくれた[@Shog9](https://stackexchange.com/users/620/shog9)に感謝します。)

Answer (score 4):

前回と同様に、[2019年のデータ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3182) と比較した増減率を載せておきます。

網掛け部分は昨年も出した結果を踏まえて、どれくらいコミュニティがアクションを行っているか = "自治率" 的な割合です。

- 赤字は前年(2019)と比較して数値が減ったもの
- 青字は前年(2019)と比較して数値が増えたもの

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]