# モデレーションレポート (2021年)

Tags: 討議

スタック・オーバーフローにおける[モデレーション](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%22+is%3Aquestion)レポートを共有したいと思います。

おそらくこちらを読んでいるみなさんはご存知だと思いますが、Stack Exchange ネットワークのサイトは、一般的な他の Web サイトとは多少異なる方法でモデレートされています：

> 当ネットワークはユーザーが管理できるように設計されています。モデレーションの負担は複数の小さなタスクで分担され、そのタスクは通常ユーザーでもこなせるものです。
> -- [モデレーションの理論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/3060) / [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

もちろんこれは[モデレーター](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/)の必要性を問うものではありませんが、モデレーションの大部分は一般のユーザーによって実行されていることを意味します。サイトに貢献する時間や労力が多くなればなるほどこの取り組みを支援するための権限がより多く開放され、その結果大きな違いを生む累積的な効果を生み出します。

2021年にわたしたちのコミュニティが達成したことを振り返り... [*興味深い* 統計](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KZntT.gif)を見てみましょう。以下は、過去12か月間にスタック・オーバーフローで実行されたモデレーションの内訳です：

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Users suspended² | 3 | 4 |
| Users destroyed³ | 106 | 0 |
| Users deleted | 1 | 0 |
| Users contacted | 4 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Suggested Edit queue | 50 | 112 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Reopen Vote queue | 9 | 26 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Low Quality Posts queue | 5 | 48 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Late Answer queue | 28 | 86 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First questions queue | 100 | 525 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First Post queue | 159 | 975 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: First answers queue | 33 | 102 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: Close Votes queue | 30 | 224 |
| Tags merged | 6 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 7 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 6 | 0 |
| Tag highlight language set | 4 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 3 | 0 |
| Questions reopened | 19 | 0 |
| Questions migrated | 2 | 0 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 9 | 217 |
| Questions closed | 253 | 32 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 195 | 31 |
| Posts unlocked | 0 | 2 |
| Posts undeleted | 1 | 85 |
| Posts locked | 2 | 15 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 95 | 1945 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 1567 |
| Comments undeleted | 3 | 0 |
| Comments flagged | 1 | 50 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 570 | 1015 |
| Comment flags handled | 45 | 6 |
| Answers flagged | 8 | 198 |
| Answer flags handled | 185 | 21 |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 2 | 0 |

#### 脚注

¹ ここでの「コミュニティー」とは[スタック・オーバーフローのユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users)を指し、名前の横にダイヤモンドの付くユーザー（モデレーター）と自動処理を行う[コミュニティボット](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)は**除きます**。

² システムは次の3つの理由でユーザーを一時停止する場合があります： ユーザーが以前に一時停止を受けた後に再生成されたとき、スパムや悪用のために破棄された後に再生成されたとき、アカウントがネットーワーク全体で一時停止の措置を受けたとき。

³ 「破棄された」ユーザーは、投稿したすべての質問（回答、コメント）とともに削除されます。[Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ 送信済みのレビューが全て含まれます（スキップされたものは除きます）。2つの編集の提案を承認するために必要なレビューは2とカウントされます。モデレーションのアクションの頻度を示すためで、通報などにも当てはまります。

⁵ クローズの通報は含まれます（クローズや再オープンの投票は*除き*ます）。

⁶ その他のアクションによって引き起こされる多数の自動削除は含まれません。

⁷ 投稿者本人によって削除されたコメントも含まれます（いくつかの通報されたコメントです）。

#### 参考文献

- 昨年からの数字の変化を知りたい方はこちら： [モデレーションレポート (2020年)](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3474/9077)
- [他のサイト](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222021%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)でもこのレポートを確認できます（英語）
- 或いは[全サイトでクローズ及び再オープンされた質問の数に関する詳細情報](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/374784/208518)を熟読

みなさんにとって2022年が素晴らしい一年となりますように！ ^_^

Answer (score 2):

前回と同様に、[2020年のデータ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3474) と比較した増減率を載せておきます。

網掛け部分は昨年も出した結果を踏まえて、どれくらいコミュニティがアクションを行っているか = "自治率" 的な割合です。

- 赤字は前年(2020)と比較して数値が減ったもの
- 青字は前年(2020)と比較して数値が増えたもの

トピックとしては「初めての投稿」が「質問」と「回答」に (年の途中から) 分かれるようになりました。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]