# モデレーションレポート (2022年)

Tags: 討議, モデレーション, 統計

今年もスタック・オーバーフローにおける[モデレーションレポート](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%E3%83%A2%E3%83%87%E3%83%AC%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B7%E3%83%A7%E3%83%B3%E3%83%AC%E3%83%9D%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%22%20is%3Aquestion)を共有したいと思います。

おそらくこちらを読んでいるみなさんはご存知だと思いますが、Stack Exchange ネットワークのサイトは、一般的な他の Web サイトとは多少異なる方法でモデレートされています：

> 当ネットワークはユーザーが管理できるように設計されています。モデレーションの負担は複数の小さなタスクで分担され、そのタスクは通常ユーザーでもこなせるものです。
> -- [モデレーションの理論](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2517/3060) / [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

もちろんこれは[モデレーター](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/)の必要性を問うものではありませんが、モデレーションの大部分は一般のユーザーによって実行されていることを意味します。サイトに貢献する時間や労力が多くなればなるほどこの取り組みを支援するための権限がより多く開放され、その結果大きな違いを生む累積的な効果を生み出します。

2022年にわたしたちのコミュニティが達成したことを振り返り（毎年一月は足早に過ぎ去ってしまいこのレポートを共有するのが二月になってしまっていますが）...[**興味深い**統計](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0TPg.gif)を見てみましょう。以下は、過去12か月間にスタック・オーバーフローで実行されたモデレーションの内訳です：

| Action | Moderators | Community¹ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| All comments on a post moved to chat | 9 | 0 |
| Answer flags handled | 176 | 34 |
| Answers flagged | 3 | 207 |
| Comment flags handled | 84 | 4 |
| Comments deleted⁷ | 595 | 809 |
| Comments flagged | 2 | 86 |
| Comments undeleted | 9 | 0 |
| Escalations to the Community Manager team | 6 | 0 |
| Posts bumped | 0 | 1,400 |
| Posts deleted⁶ | 77 | 1,573 |
| Posts locked | 3 | 12 |
| Posts undeleted | 3 | 57 |
| Posts unlocked | 1 | 3 |
| Question flags handled⁵ | 66 | 10 |
| Questions closed | 222 | 23 |
| Questions flagged⁵ | 11 | 65 |
| Questions migrated | 2 | 1 |
| Questions reopened | 26 | 0 |
| Revisions redacted | 4 | 0 |
| Tag highlight language set | 6 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms created | 7 | 0 |
| Tag synonyms proposed | 7 | 0 |
| Tags merged | 5 | 0 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Close votes" queue | 28 | 223 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First answers" queue | 145 | 185 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "First questions" queue | 173 | 1,344 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Late answers" queue | 30 | 68 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Low quality posts" queue | 8 | 10 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Reopen votes" queue | 4 | 5 |
| Tasks reviewed⁴: "Suggested edits" queue | 64 | 154 |
| Users contacted | 5 | 0 |
| Users destroyed³ | 2 | 0 |
| Users suspended² | 5 | 19 |

#### 脚注

¹ ここでの「Community」とは[スタック・オーバーフローのユーザー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users)を指し、名前の横にダイヤモンドの付くユーザー（モデレーター）と自動処理を行う[コミュニティボット](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/-1)は**除きます**。

² システムは次の3つの理由でユーザーを一時停止する場合があります： ユーザーが以前に一時停止を受けた後に再生成されたとき、スパムや悪用のために破棄された後に再生成されたとき、アカウントがネットーワーク全体で一時停止の措置を受けたとき。

³ 「破棄された」ユーザーは、投稿したすべての質問（回答、コメント）とともに削除されます。[Generally used as an expedient way of getting rid of spam.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88994/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deleted-user-and-a-destroyed-user)

⁴ 送信済みのレビューが全て含まれます（スキップされたものは除きます）。2つの編集の提案を承認するために必要なレビューは2とカウントされます。モデレーションのアクションの頻度を示すためで、通報などにも当てはまります。

⁵ クローズの通報は含まれます（クローズや再オープンの投票は**除き**ます）。クローズの通報を受けた質問に 1 人以上のユーザーがクローズ票を投じた際、コミュニティが処理を進めます。

⁶ その他のアクションによって引き起こされる多数の自動削除は含まれません。

⁷ 投稿者本人によって削除されたコメントも含まれます（いくつかの通報されたコメントです）。

#### 参考文献

- [他のサイト](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A%222022%3A+a+year+in+moderation%22)でもモデレーションレポートを確認できます（英語）
- 或いは[全サイトでクローズ及び再オープンされた質問の数に関する詳細情報](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/386090/208518)を熟読

2023年も皆さまにとって実り多き一年となりますよう、お祈り申し上げます。 ^_^

Answer (score 2):

前回と同様に、[2021年のデータ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3687/3060) と比較した増減率を載せておきます。

網掛け部分は昨年も出した結果を踏まえて、どれくらいコミュニティがアクションを行っているか = "自治率" 的な割合です。

- 赤字は前年と比較して数値が減ったもの
- 青字は前年と比較して数値が増えたもの

見出しで黄色に塗っているのは、今回分から追加 (途中で変更) された項目です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]